# What does the code does and how can i use it in my custom projects?

Tags: c++, qt

I fount the below code in QT header file named "mywidget.h".
Could any one please clarify the below questions:

1. What the code does ?
2. Is it a good practice ?
3. Where can I find similar kind of code snippets to enhance my knowledge?

```c
     #ifndef %PRE_DEF%
     #define %PRE_DEF%

        #include <%BASECLASS%>

        class %CLASS% : public %BASECLASS%
        {
            Q_OBJECT

        public:
            %CLASS%(QWidget *parent = 0);
            ~%CLASS%();
        };

        #endif // %PRE_DEF%
```

Comment: This is probably used for automatic code generation, I'm not sure though

Comment: Qt includes a prebuild step which will convert these `%THINGS%` into valid c++, prior to being compiled. Why do you want to do similar in your projects? It seems you're looking for a solution to a problem you don't have.

Answer (score 1):

This code is just a code snippet used to create new class.

**What it does?**

It just inserts this code snippet into your text/source file and selects ( or marks ) all `%NAME% keywords which let's you change it to desired name.

**Is it a good practice?**

It depends. If you're tired of typing new classes and you know how to do this then answer is yes it is. It let's you create object definitions in less steps.

**Where can I find similar kind of code snippets to enhance my knowledge?**

This depends on IDE you're using. With Visual Studio you can add these in :

`C:\Users\your_username\Documents\Visual Studio version\Code Snippets`

There you'll find different folders named like `Visual C++` in which you can add them.

**EDIT:**

Answering to the comment:

You dont have to use any kind of IDE, you can just copy the content by hand and modify it. But ( just for clarity ) it's easier to use IDE instead of hand copying and changing the content.

Complete explanation on how to use code snippets:

[Qt Creator](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-completing-code.html)

[Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx)

Comment: Does it mean that I require a IDE support to use similar code snippets in my project? Can you please explain it or provide a link so that I can get more info about them?